# How to select those record just first 7

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table `t1` like

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+------+
| id   | level | gap  |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     6 |   50 |
|    1 |     5 |   10 |
|    2 |     5 |   12 |
|    2 |     5 |   10 |
|    3 |     8 |    4 |
|    3 |     9 |    1 |
|    3 |     9 |    3 |
|    3 |     7 |    2 |
|    4 |     8 |   10 |
|    4 |     8 |    2 |
|    4 |     9 |    6 |
|    4 |     9 |    4 |
+------+-------+------+
```

Of course I can use

```
select * from t1 where id=3;
```

to get all record of `id=3`:

```
mysql> select * from t1 where id=3;
+------+-------+------+
| id   | level | gap  |
+------+-------+------+
|    3 |     8 |    4 |
|    3 |     9 |    1 |
|    3 |     9 |    3 |
|    3 |     7 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+
```

But I just hope the result from first 7.I mean it should be the **red rectangle part**:

[image]

How to write such command?

Comment: Clarify your question with more textual explanations.

Comment: I think this question is clear,which shouldn't get so many downvote..

Comment: The question title says "first 10", then in the question you say "first 7", but first 7 of what? What columns are ordering your table? Maybe that's why you get downvotes, it isn't clear.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I'm sorry for that,it is a typo indeed.And I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner select gets the first 7 records - don't forget to add an `order by` to get a garanteed result

```
select *
from
(    
    select * 
    from t1 
    order by some_column
    limit 7    
) tmp
where id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks,if I omit the `order by some_column`,it will work for me.

Comment: You need to add an order to get a garanteed result. Otherwise it is just luck which 7 records get returned. There is no default order in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

If the schema is organized like that, you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 LIMIT 7) WHERE id=3
```

Comment: Maybe you mean the [below method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aTk7p.png).But actually it doesn't work..

Comment: @yode Sorry, I misinterpreted your question

Comment: Thanks very much.And as your  prompt `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 LIMIT 7) As tem WHERE id=3;` is work for me. :)